# How can a function have a finite area but infinite volume when revolved around an axis?

Tags: integration, logarithms, volume, infinity, solid-of-revolution

I have a function $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ on $[0, \pi]$ and want to find the area of the function, then the volume of the function were it revolved around the x-axis.

For the area:

$$\begin{align}
A &= \int_0^\pi \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx \\
&= \int_0^\pi \frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}} \, dx \\
&= \int_0^\pi x^{\frac{-1}{2}} \, dx \\
&= \left[ \frac{x^{\left(\frac{-1}{2}+1\right)}}{\left(\frac{-1}{2}+1\right)} \right]_0^\pi \\
&= \left[\frac{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)}\right]_0^\pi \\
&= \left[2x^{\frac{1}{2}}\right]_0^\pi \\
&= \left[2\sqrt{x}\right]_0^\pi \\
&= 2\sqrt{\pi} - 2\sqrt{0} \\
&= 2\sqrt{\pi}
\end{align}$$

The area $A$ of $f(x)$ on $[0, \pi]$ is finite. Now revolving around the x-axis:

$$\begin{align}
V &= \int_0^\pi \pi\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^2 \, dx \\
&= \int_0^\pi \pi\left(\frac{1^2}{\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2}\right) \, dx \\
&= \int_0^\pi \pi\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \, dx \\
&= \int_0^\pi \frac{\pi}{x} \, dx \\
&= \left[\pi \ln{x}\right]_0^\pi \\
&= \pi \left[\ln{x}\right]_0^\pi \\
&= \pi (\ln{\pi} - \ln{0})
\end{align}$$

Note $\ln{x}$ is undefined for $x = 0$ and complex for $x \lt 0$, thus the volume $V$ of $f(x)$ over $[0, \pi]$ is not finite.

How can an area of a function be finite, yet the volume of the same function rotated around an axis be infinite/undefined? Is this a quirk of the mathematics or I haven't yet learned how to find the volume of shapes like this? I don't know if the mathematics here is definitive or it's undefined as a consequence of my (lack of) knowledge.

Comment: You showed how, quite in some detail.

Comment: It’s called a “paradox”, which means something which is *seemingly* contradictory but may in fact be true, or that is contrary to perceived opinions or expectations. The infinite is often paradoxical. Note that physical intuition here is useless, since you run into quantum mechanical and Planck length issues.

Comment: The same way a 2D shape can have infinite circumference but finite area. (E.g., Koch's snowflake.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you integrate to compute the volume of the solid of revolution, you are integrating the square of the function. It turns out that $\frac 1{\sqrt x}$ is not square integrable, and the integral diverges to $+\infty$. Any function that is integrable but not square integrable will give finite area but infinite volume.